# Exception when starting Snapshot Agent when setting up database replication

Tags: sql, sql-server, replication, database-replication, transactional-replication

I am trying to set up replication between databases. I followed this tutorials:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/tutorial-preparing-the-server-for-replication?view=sql-server-ver15

and after:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/tutorial-replicating-data-between-continuously-connected-servers?view=sql-server-ver15

I went through first without any problems. Almost completed the second, but I stuck on step [View the status of snapshot generation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/tutorial-replicating-data-between-continuously-connected-servers?view=sql-server-ver15#view-the-status-of-snapshot-generation)

When I try to strat snapshot agent, I get error:

> Exception Message: An unspecified error had occurred in the native SQL Server connection component.

I tried to search on the internet MSSQL_REPL55012 (that's error code I get), but didn't succeed.

I tried to look in SQL Profiler, Jobs history, Replication Monitor, even ran failing job step from PowerShell, but couldn't get any more info on that.

What might be the issue? Anybody else stumbled upon that?

I am using:

- SSMS version 15.0.18206.0
- SQL Server engine 15.0.2000.5

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I finally got it resolved. The issue was missing OLE DB driver.

I just downloaded [latest driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/download-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15). Then I got `msoledbsqlr.rll` driver in directory `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\1033`. Then I copied to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\COM` directory, so it can be found by `snapshot.exe`, which is executable run by Snapshot Agent.

Alternatvely, one can define environmental variable to point to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\1033` direcotry, so it will be found there.

Another issue might be that 64-bit SQL tries to use 32-bit drivers (`msoledbsql.dll`, `msoledbsqlr.rll`), but it wasn't issue in my case.

Comment: Still issue with last SQL Server version 15.0.2000.5 (X64). Workaround works, thank you!

Comment: For me there was no need to update the driver. Simply copy the msoledbsqlr.rll file as described was enough to get it working. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I know this question was answered but for future reference ,updating SQL server 2019 to latest CU solved for me.

Comment: . it solved the problem with a raw 2019 install. got CU and everything is working.